# Cakephp 2.x multiple relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.x

i have some troubles with cakephp 2.x and the relationship of the models, i have 3 models, Post, User and Comment.
I would like bind the Post with his User and Comment with his User.

In Post Model:

```
   $belongsTo = array('Comment','User'),
   $hasMany = array('CommentOfPost'=>array('className'=>'Comment'));
```

I have Post bind with User, and all comment from the post but i don't have users of the comments.

Edit :

Sql output

```
   1    SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`content`, `Post`.`tags`, `Post`.`created`,  `Post`.`modified`, `Post`.`user_id`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`lastname`, `User`.`birthdate`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `blog`.`posts` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `blog`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Post`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE `Post`.`id` = 16 LIMIT 1        1   1   0
   2    SELECT `CommentOfPost`.`id`, `CommentOfPost`.`post_id`, `CommentOfPost`.`user_id`, `CommentOfPost`.`content`, `CommentOfPost`.`created` FROM `blog`.`comments` AS `CommentOfPost` WHERE `CommentOfPost`.`post_id` = (16)
```

Edit :
Comment Model

```
    public $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User'));
```

Post Model

```
    public $belongsTo = array('Comment' => array('className' => 'Comment'));
```

Edit :

Thank for reply, i have the same result like before i have Post and his User and Post and his comments but not users of comments

Now my model Post

```
    $hasMany = array(
            'Comment' => array(
                'className' => 'Comment',
            )
        ),
        $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
            )
        );
```

User model

```
   $hasMany = array('Comment' => array('className' => 'Comment'));
```

Comment Model

```
   $belongsTo = array('Users' => array('className' => 'User'), 'Posts' => array('clasName' => 'Post'));
```

I use paginate querying in my PostsController

```
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;

    $data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post');
    $this->set('posts', $data);
```

Edit :

My paginate params

```
    $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 10,
    'recursive' => 2,
    'order' => array(
        'Post.id' => 'desc'
    )
);
```

I try with and without recursive option

Ok it's done !

For resume i have :

```
   class User extends AppModel {
       public $hasMany = array('Comment' => array('className' => 'Comment'));
   }

   class Post extends AppModel 
   {
       $hasMany = array(
            'Comment' => array(
                'className' => 'Comment',
            )
        ),
        $belongsTo = array(
            'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
            )
        );
    }

    class Comment extends AppModel {
        public $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'User'), 'Post' => array('clasName' => 'Post'));
```

}

```
    PostsController extends AppController
    {
        ....

        $this->Post->recursive = 2;
        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);

        ...
    }
```

Thank for your help guys, you're awesome !

Comment: Could provide also your `find()` expression?

Comment: Could you append to your pagination params array `'recursive' => 2`?

Comment: Do you use the Containable behaviour in your AppModel?

Comment: No i don't use, i even try with `findById()` i get the good post with his user and coments but not users comments i try with `$this->Post->recusrive = 2;` but no effect ... think i'm stupid

Answer (score 0):

`Post` does not belongs to `Comment`. It has many `comments`.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Example from the cookbook:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MyRecipe' => array(
            'className' => 'Recipe',
        )
    );
}
```

For your application:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment',
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: And also, a `User` has many `Comment`, and a `Comment` belongs to both a `Post` and a `User`.

Comment: Maybe you should check witch primary keys your relation wants.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Here you can find more options to set into your relation-array... If it won't work we can chat!

Comment: Hi Bob, i would like to chat if you are available, thank